# reverse a string without reverse() method. what am i doing wrong

Tags: c++, string

Could someone tell me why this doesn't work?
I want to check if a word is a palindrome (without using reverse() method)

```
bool check(const string & s)
{
    string temp;
    int count = 0;

    for (long i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--, count++)
        temp[count] = s[i];

    cout << temp;
    if (temp == s)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: resize your string `temp` to the size of `s` before you start the loop.

Comment: temp is declared as string and you are using it as an array?

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not an acceptable problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at these two specific lines:

```
string temp;

    temp[count] = s[i];
```

In the first line you declare an *empty* string object. Then in the second you try to write to the index `count` of the empty string. And since the string is empty the index will be out of bounds. Indexing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Instead the second line could be e.g.

```
    temp += s[i];
```

That will append the characters to the string `temp`, and *extend* the string as needed.

***Or*** you could set the size of the temporary string to the same size as the input string:

```
string temp{s,size(), ' '};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to correct your code:

1. Define the size of the temp string.

   `char temp[s.size]; //Something similar to this.`
2. `string temp;` creates a empty string and you can append the reverse string to empty string using append assignment operator. `temp+=s[i];`

Here is the corrected code:

```
bool check(const string & s)
{
    string temp;
    //int count = 0;

    for (long i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        temp += s[i];
        //temp[count] = s[i];

    cout << temp;
    if (temp == s)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```